# How to access zip central directory with c++

Tags: c++, zip

I have a task to create a c++ console application that can access various data (editing the comment, reading names of files in the zip archive, reading data in the header or central directory etc.) from a zip file. I am allowed to use only basic libraries

I did some googling and found the zip file structure, then i made a simple code to check if i can read any data with ifstream, it returned various characters (which after further googling seem to represent hexadecimal values in UTF-8 encoding). That's where my fairly limited knowledge and what i can find in google ends.

How do i properly read the various info included in the zip file then?

Comment: Parse the data from the zip archive

Comment: I suggest you first use a so-called "hex editor" to analyse the header of a .zip file manually and to modify its contents. Once you are able to accomplish the task manually using a hex editor, you can think about how to accomplish it automatically using a C++ program.

Comment: Of course, make sure you have a backup of your .zip file before editing it, because if you do someting wrong, you may no longer be able to read the contents of the .zip file.

Comment: When opening a .zip file in C/C++, make sure you open it in binary mode and not in text mode. Otherwise, depending on your platform, you may read garbage data.

Comment: Zip is a binary format. For the metadata, like the file header, you would mostly have to read binary values (ints, shorts) from the file. First figure out how to do that. Since this is obviously homework, you probably won't get a straightforward answer (also, some professors watch StackOverflow, just saying).

Comment: What part of the zip file did you try to read, and what led you to believe that you were looking at UTF-8 encoded data?

Comment: I've realized my mistake, i've tried to read a binary file like i would read a text file (and using "int" only returned 0s which only confused me more). Im learning how to open files in binary mode now and with help of hex editor i think i'll understand the zip format and figure out how to finish the task. Thanks for all your answers and not beeing too harsh on a c++ newbie.